# Approval To Edit A Document

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, approval

I have a requirement to only allow users to Edit documents in a Document Library when they have been approved to do so.  This would require removal of permissions after they have completed their edits.

I had looked at in-place records management as one option around doing this - i.e. make major versions of a document into an in-place record and any new edits would be done on another version of the document, thus incrementing the major version.

Are there simpler OOTB ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very understand of your requirement.

Do you mean you want to remove edit permissions after they have completed their edits?

Create an 2010 platform workflow on the New user request list and Replace View Only of item in Current Item:

[image]

More detailed information, refer to the article:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html

Comment: Yes after an end-user has completed their testing their permissions would be removed.  They would subsequently need to seek approval to edit again.  This is the crazy business requirement I have been presented with.

Comment: check the method i have offered.

Comment: This is a SharePoint 2010 workflow - considering this -> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Sharepoint-2010-Workflow-can-no-longer-be-published-on/m-p/364112 it does not seem like this will work in SharePoint Online.  Is there an option in Flow for this?